Can not get information from a website using RSelenium
I would like to use RSelenium to scrape a webpage to check if a certain text exists.
I need to click on Staatsangehörigkeitsangelegenheiten followed by clicking 02. Antrag Einbürgerung [sorry as the website is in German].
I tried the following:
require(RSelenium)
URL <- "https://halle.de/serviceportal/online-terminvergabe/online-terminvereinbarung-einbuergerungsbehoerde-standesamt"

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr$navigate(URL)

# this works to get the page title
ReadyDown2 <- remDr$getTitle()

# none of the follwing work
xpath0 <- '//*[@id="category_ceb42d82-215c-4565-80f1-e2af5e77859c"]'
idd <- 'category_ceb42d82-215c-4565-80f1-e2af5e77859c'
DownLink <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", xpath0)
DownLink <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "Datenschutz")

What I am actually would like to get is to find if the following text exists Keine freien Termine gefunden. after clicking on both links.
NB: the website did not work for me as expected after I click the links on Firefox.
Is it possible to implement this using RSelenium or rvest in windows?
Thanks

Theres an <iframe> who leads to another url:
<iframe class="showmobile" border="0" src="https://itc-halle.saas.smartcjm.com/m/standesamt/extern/calendar/?uid=9da900ff-e9a5-46be-a622-ecdfa078121c" name="Standesamt Onlinetermin - iFrame" width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0" aria-label="Standesamt Onlinetermin"> 

On this one, you'll find your xpath:
# Consider `selenider` instead of `RSelenium`
library(selenider)

aux <- open_url("https://itc-halle.saas.smartcjm.com/m/standesamt/extern/calendar/?uid=9da900ff-e9a5-46be-a622-ecdfa078121c")

find_element(aux, xpath = '//*[@id="category_ceb42d82-215c-4565-80f1-e2af5e77859c"]')

It gives:
{ selenider_element }
<div class="title" id="category_ceb42d82-215c-4565-80f1-e2af5e77859c" onclick="switchAccordion('ceb42d82-215c-4565-80f1-e2af5e77859c');">
  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<i class="dropdown icon"></i>Staatsangehörigkeitsangelegenheiten
</div>

The site:

If think what you might want is just one (or few) click(s) away at id="category_content_ceb42d82-215c-4565-80f1-e2af5e77859c".
Take a look at selenider::elem_scroll_to and elem_click.
Hope it helps.
